# Family distribution for continuous count data

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, count-data, continuous-data

I need to model the variable *Total motile Count* which describe *how many million sperm cells in an entire ejaculate are motile*. It is not a proper count since it is calculated as a product of other variables: sperm count(x10^6/mL) x motility(%) x volume(mL).

Therefore, it is not continuous. There are no zeroes (min=2 max=650, mean=129.56, var=10916.37).
What family of distribution should I consider to model Total motile Count as response variable?
I considered Gamma because the number of counts is very high and quasi-poisson distribution. What do you suggest?
I tried Poisson and negative binomial (overdispersion parameter = 0.6063, CI: 0.4375-0.8403), suggesting that the latter is preferred (smallest AIC, also over Gamma).
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why not model these data in exactly the way stated: namely, as a (known) multiple of a Poisson variable??

Answer (score -1):

If motility is constant, Total motile Count  is also a Poisson distribution.

Y = sperm count(x10^6/mL) x motility(%) x volume(mL).

E[Y] = E[sperm count]*(x10^6/mL) x motility(%) x volume(mL).

Comment: A multiple of a Poisson variable *never* has a Poisson distribution unless the multiple is $0$ or $1.$